# how to Find string length without white spaces and functions in php

Tags: php

I have assignment to find the length of string without white space and without using any string function anyone help me please

Comment: School's really do set such ridiculous problems.... split to an array, filter out the spaces, then count

Comment: @MarkBaker what's ridiculous about it? It shows students that there are many ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Aziz - what's ridiculous is that you'll never have to do equivalent tasks in the real world; when a function exists that does exactly what you need, you'll be expected to use it, and not write your own version of that function while having your hands cuffed behind your back

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree with your sentiment; maybe teachers are doing it on purpose to point out how inefficient it is so that in the future, in other situations, they will understand why things are done in a certain way instead of wondering "Why can't I just use this working code?"

Comment: I just wish teachers would teach accepted solutions for real world problems like SQL injection, etc

Comment: I wish teachers would teach their students how to do basic debugging, how to write tests, about version control, and all the other tasks that differentiate professional developers from amateurs

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions and the function [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$value = "This is a test string.";
$length = preg_match_all ('/[^ ]/' , $value, $matches);
echo $length; //18
```

Here you can find a working example: https://3v4l.org/IPlJi

**explanation:**
Between `[^` and `]` you have to add all characters which should not be count to the length of the string. For example: if you want to filter out the character `i` and  (space) you have to set the following pattern: `[^ i]`.

Code to filter `i` and  (space):

```
$value = "This is a test string.";
$length = preg_match_all('/[^ i]/' , $value, $matches);
echo $length; //15
```

**be carefull with some characters:**
If you want to exclude one of the following characters `.^$*+?()[{\|` you have to escape them with `\`. If you want to exclude the `.` too, you have the following code:

```
$value = "This is a test string.";
$length = preg_match_all ('/[^ \.]/' , $value, $matches);
echo $length; //18
```

**how to test your pattern:**
If you want to test your regular expressions for `preg_match_all` or other functions like that, you can use the following tool: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
$string = "this is a nice string with spaces and chars";
$length = 0;
$i = 0;
while(isset($string[$i]))
{
  if($string[$i] != ' ') $length++;
  $i++;
}
var_dump($length);
var_dump(strlen($string));
```

Outputs:

```
int(35) 
int(43)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <form action="#" method="get">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="txt"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <br><br>
      </form>
      <!---------------------------------------------------------------------->  
<?php
if(isset($_GET["submit"])) {
    $name = $_GET["txt"];
    for ($i = 0; isset($name[$i]); $i++) {
        $j = $i;
    }
    for ($k = $j; isset($name[$k]); $k--) {
        echo $name[$k];
    }
}
```